# vb.net formatting URL characters

Tags: vb.net

If I have a string that contains:

```
Dim URLString As String = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
```

And I want to get a formatted result like this:

```
Dim result As String = "stackoverflow.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function:

```
public string getDomainName(String url) 
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    String domain = uri.Host;
    return domain.StartsWith("www.") ? domain.Substring(4) : domain;
}
```

Comment: Note that since an url can be http/https/ftp/etc, and a url can or cannot contains the www, or can contain it as part of an username/pass, RegEx is a the only real approach.